# header menu with a logo left is not being displayed

Tags: html, css

I am new with HTML & CSS, and I Am having a weird issue where the logo path is properly rendered into the page, but however doesn't display on the site. how does it happen this? e.g. the logo is a SVG format where I don't see it's an issue, but I am not sure why it behaves like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <header> <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
      <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/128647/download.svg" alt="header-logo">
      </div>

      <nav class="header-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">demo1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
header {
  padding: 5% 5% 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-logo {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.header-menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.header-menu li {
  margin-right: 40px;
  color: hsl(243, 87%, 12%);
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header-menu li:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  background: hsl(260, 100%, 75%);
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.header-menu li:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your logo a width and height.

```
<img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/128647/download.svg" height="150" width="150" alt="header-logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your CSS:

```
    .header-logo {
  width: 2rem;
}
```

If you face any problem then let me know.